App filters not working. What logical error could have been made?
`When you select certain filters, the buttons will work, but nothing will happen, if you go to the main screen and look at the dishes, they will be unchanged, and if you return to the section with filters, they will be in the default position
I am attaching a link to the program on GitHub: https://github.com/MARAN1GHTON/Food-catalog
presumably the problem may be in these two classes:`
Filters
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_catalog/screens/tabs.dart';
import 'package:food_catalog/widgets/main_drawer.dart';

enum Filter {
  glutenFree,
  lactoseFree,
  vegetarian,
  vegan,
}

class FiltersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FiltersScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.currentFilters,
  });

  final Map<Filter, bool> currentFilters;

  @override
  State<FiltersScreen> createState() => _FiltersScreenState();
}

class _FiltersScreenState extends State<FiltersScreen> {
  var _glutenFreeFilterSet = false;
  var _lactoseFreeFilterSet = false;
  var _vegetarianFilterSet = false;
  var _veganFilterSet = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _glutenFreeFilterSet = widget.currentFilters[Filter.glutenFree]!;
    _lactoseFreeFilterSet = widget.currentFilters[Filter.lactoseFree]!;
    _vegetarianFilterSet = widget.currentFilters[Filter.vegetarian]!;
    _veganFilterSet = widget.currentFilters[Filter.vegan]!;
  }

  void _saveFilters() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop({
      Filter.glutenFree: _glutenFreeFilterSet,
      Filter.lactoseFree: _lactoseFreeFilterSet,
      Filter.vegetarian: _vegetarianFilterSet,
      Filter.vegan: _veganFilterSet,
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      onPopInvokedWithResult: (didPop, result) {
        if (didPop) {
          _saveFilters();
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Ваши фильтры'),
        ),
        drawer: MainDrawer(onSelectScreen: (identifier) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          if (identifier == 'meals') {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const TabsScreen(),
              ),
            );
          }
        }),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SwitchListTile(
              value: _lactoseFreeFilterSet,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _lactoseFreeFilterSet = newValue;
                });
              },
              title: Text(
                'Не содержит лактозу',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    ),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(
                'Показать только блюда без лактозы',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium!.copyWith(
                      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    ),
              ),
              activeColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 34, right: 22),
            ),
            SwitchListTile(
              value: _glutenFreeFilterSet,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _glutenFreeFilterSet = newValue;
                });
              },
              title: Text(
                'Толькое блюда без глютена',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    ),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(
                'Показать только блюда без глютена',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium!.copyWith(
                      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    ),
              ),
              activeColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 34, right: 22),
            ),
            SwitchListTile(
              value: _vegetarianFilterSet,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _vegetarianFilterSet = newValue;
                });
              },
              title: Text(
                'Толькое вегариантские блюда',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    ),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(
                'Показать только вегатариантые блюда',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium!.copyWith(
                      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    ),
              ),
              activeColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 34, right: 22),
            ),
            SwitchListTile(
              value: _veganFilterSet,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _veganFilterSet = newValue;
                });
              },
              title: Text(
                'Только веганские блюда',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    ),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(
                'Показать только веганские блюда',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium!.copyWith(
                      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    ),
              ),
              activeColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 34, right: 22),
            ),
            //),
          ],
        ),
        //),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Tabs
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_catalog/data/dummy_data.dart';
import 'package:food_catalog/models/meal.dart';
import 'package:food_catalog/screens/category_view.dart';
import 'package:food_catalog/screens/filters.dart';
import 'package:food_catalog/screens/meals.dart';
import 'package:food_catalog/widgets/main_drawer.dart';

const kInitialFilters = {
  Filter.glutenFree: false,
  Filter.lactoseFree: false,
  Filter.vegetarian: false,
  Filter.vegan: false,
};

class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TabsScreen> createState() => _TabsScreenState();
}

class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {
  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;
  final List<Meal> _favoriteMeals = [];
  Map<Filter, bool> _selectedFilters = kInitialFilters;

  void _showInfoMessage(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(message),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _toggleMealFavoriteStatus(Meal meal) {
    final isExisting = _favoriteMeals.contains(meal);

    if (isExisting) {
      setState(() {
        _favoriteMeals.remove(meal);
      });
      _showInfoMessage('Чао персик, дозревай');
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _favoriteMeals.add(meal);

        _showInfoMessage('Опа чиназес, сюда!');
      });
    }
  }

  void _selectedPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void _setScreen(String identifier) async {
    Navigator.of(context).pop
        //<Map<Filter, bool>>
        ();
    if (identifier == "filtres") {
      final result = await Navigator.of(context).push<Map<Filter, bool>>(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => FiltersScreen(
            currentFilters: _selectedFilters,
          ),
        ),
      );
      print(result);
      setState(() {
        _selectedFilters = result ?? kInitialFilters;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final availableMeals = dummyMeals.where((meal) {
      if (_selectedFilters[Filter.glutenFree]! && !meal.isGlutenFree) {
        return false;
      }
      if (_selectedFilters[Filter.lactoseFree]! && !meal.isLactoseFree) {
        return false;
      }
      if (_selectedFilters[Filter.vegetarian]! && !meal.isVegetarian) {
        return false;
      }
      if (_selectedFilters[Filter.vegan]! && !meal.isVegan) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }).toList();
    Widget activePage = CategoriesScreen(
      onToggleFavorite: _toggleMealFavoriteStatus,
      availebleMeals: availableMeals,
    );
    var activePageTittle = 'Категории';

    if (_selectedPageIndex == 1) {
      activePage = MealsScreen(
        meals: _favoriteMeals,
        onToggleFavorite: _toggleMealFavoriteStatus,
      );
      activePageTittle = 'Избранное';
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(activePageTittle),
      ),
      drawer: MainDrawer(
        onSelectScreen: _setScreen,
      ),
      body: activePage,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _selectedPage,
        currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.set_meal), label: "Категории"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.stars), label: "Избранное"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

The code does not produce any errors, perhaps the problem lies in the logic itself, or in a typo that the compiler does not see
